Why does using the mode attribute in my XSLT just make it print the whole XML?
Working on a larger transform, but was able to replicate this in a mock-up. If I use the "mode" attribute in my XSLT template, the result is just the raw text (without markup) of the original XML that is supposed to be transformed. If I instead use the "name" attribute, it transforms as expected.
XML
<Parent>
 <ParentCon>Parent Content</ParentCon>
 <Child>
  <ChildCon>Child Content</ChildCon>
  <Grandchild>Some Grandchild Content</Grandchild>
 </Child>
</Parent>

XSLT (with mode attribute)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="Parent" mode="xyz">

    <ExportParent>
       <ExportChild>
      </ExportChild>
    </ExportParent>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Output (with mode attribute)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 Parent Content
 
  Child Content
  Some Grandchild Content

XSLT (with name attribute)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="Parent" name="xyz">

    <ExportParent>
       <ExportChild>
      </ExportChild>
    </ExportParent>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Output (with name attribute)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ExportParent><ExportChild/></ExportParent>

Googling suggests that name and mode are functionally the same, except mode allows for re-use.
I expected the output to be the same with both attributes.

name and mode are not at all the same. It is best to read the specification itself  instead of relying on random sources found by Googling.

The problem with your template with mode attribute is that it is never applied, and the entire transformation is performed using only the built-in template rules.
The XSLT 1.0 specification states that:

if an xsl:apply-templates element does not have a mode attribute, then
it applies only to those template rules from xsl:template elements
that do not have a mode attribute.

There is no xsl:apply-templates instruction in your XSLT, and the built-in template rule applies templates without mode.
The result of processing an XML using only the built-in template rules is a copy of all the text nodes in the input document.
The name of a template plays no role unless you are calling the template by its name.
See:
https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#modes
https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#built-in-rule
https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#named-templates

Default processing applies templates that are not in a mode. There are built-in templates that fire, which apply-templates to child nodes, and a default template for text() that returns the text. So, when those default templates match, it just spits out the text().
If you wanted to get your expected output you could create a template matching on the root node / and then inside that template apply-templates in the "xyz" mode and it would match on Parent and apply that template in that mode:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="xyz"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Parent" mode="xyz">
        
        <ExportParent>
            <ExportChild>
            </ExportChild>
        </ExportParent>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>


You need to apply templates in that mode to use the templates in that mode. XSLT 3.0 also allows you to declare the default mode:
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" default-mode="xyz">
  <xsl:template match="Parent" mode="xyz">

    <ExportParent>
       <ExportChild>
      </ExportChild>
    </ExportParent>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Example online fiddle.

XSLT templates' name and mode attribute are somewhat similar in that they are both a kind of identifier, and both used to control the circumstances in which the template applies, but they do work very differently.
XSLT is an unusual programming language in the flexibility it offers in calling a block of code, much more so than most languages. This is one of its weirdest features which programmers from other backgrounds sometimes have difficulty getting their heads around. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch
Many languages allow you to call a function by name, and many allow you to have several functions with the same name, and dispatch your function call to the appropriate function based on the function's name and also the parameters you supply when you call it. In object-oriented languages, an object also provides a way of identifying the appropriate method to call (whether the method is attached to the object directly or to one of the object's classes).
In XSLT you have two different ways to invoke a template, either:

by name, or
by pattern matching

Call by name
<xsl:call-template name="my-template"/>

This will invoke a template whose @name is my-template. It's as simple as that.
The only complexity is if you have a stylesheet containing a template named my-template, and your stylesheet imports another stylesheet which contains a template also called my-template, then the main stylesheet's template will have a higher priority, and will be invoked instead of the template in the imported stylesheet. This is to allow you to import another stylesheet and over-ride some of its functionality by effectively replacing some of the named templates.
Note that a template may legally have a name and also a mode attribute, but this is unusual coding practice. In any case, when you call a template by name, the mode is ignored. The mode attribute only comes into play when you invoke a template with apply-templates, and in those cases the mode is used in conjunction with match to decide whether a given template is applied.
Pattern-matching
The most common way to invoke a template is not by name but by pattern-matching.
A template's mode attribute is only relevant when the template is invoked by pattern matching, by calling apply-templates:
<xsl:apply-templates select="$my-nodes"/>

When you use apply-templates to invoke a template, the stylesheet processor uses the match attribute of the templates to decide which template to invoke. It will find the templates whose match pattern matches the nodes which you supplied in the select attribute of apply-templates, and from among those matching templates it will invoke the template with the highest priority (either the one with the highest priority attribute, or the one with the most complex match expression). When you invoke a template using apply-templates, the name attribute (if any) of the template is ignored.
The mode attribute provides a refinement:
<xsl:apply-templates select="$my-nodes" mode="my-mode"/>

When you call apply-templates with a specific mode, the stylesheet processor considers only the templates with a matching mode attribute. So the mode provides a way to group a set of related templates together.
If you don't specify a mode in apply-templates, or on a template element, it effectively refers to an anonymous mode.
How to use mode and think about mode
How do XSLT programmers use mode? If you have a background in object-oriented programming, you may find it helpful to get an intuitive understanding of mode by (roughly) mapping it onto an object-oriented framework:
An XSLT stylesheet containing a set of templates with no mode attributes (i.e. they all belong to the default, anonymous, mode) is like a set of classes each with a single method (let's call it default_mode), which all inherit from a base node() class whose default_mode method just calls the default_mode method for its child nodes, and where a text() class provides an implementation of the default_mode method which outputs the text value of the text node.
For the built-in anonymous mode, and for any new mode you define explicitly, the XSLT language itself provides built-in implementations of a few templates for you (and in XSLT 3 you can select from a few different such implementations).
Here, the template's match pattern is the equivalent of the class name, in an object oriented language (yes, a match pattern is much more complex than a class name, but for the sake of argument, because I'm focusing on mode, I'm going to ignore that difference).
class `document_or_element` {
   method `default_mode` ($node) {
      return `default_mode`($node/child::node());
   }
}

class `text_or_attribute` extends `node()` {
   method `default_mode`($node) {
       return string-value-of($node);
   }
}
class `comment_or_processing_instruction` extends `node()` {
   method `default_mode`($node) {
       return null;
   }
}

An XSLT stylesheet with two different modes is like a set of classes which all inherit from a base class with two methods (e.g. default_mode, and some_other_mode).
So in normal practice an XSLT mode is used to define a particular kind of processing, in the same way that a class defines multiple methods to perform different types of processing (e.g. converting the nodes into a particular kind of output format, or extracting a particular kind of information from the nodes, or something like that).
Writing a template in a particular mode is like writing a method for a new class which overrides a method of the same name in a super-class; it's to provide a specific implementation of the same general kind of processing as the super-class's method would provide.
